# Compile VxWorks using clang -cc1 option fail when adding -g debug flag

Tags: c, compilation, clang, vxworks, wind-river-workbench

I'm trying to compile VxWorks 7 SR660 on Wind River Workbench using clang version 10.0.1.1.
When compiling without debugging (-g flag) the compilation succeeds, when adding -g flag I get an error "error: unknown argument: '-g'".
The flags I use are:

```
  clang -cc1 -triple=i386 -emit-obj -mrelocation-model static  -fgnuc-version=4.2.1
     -D __VXWORKS__  -D CPU=_VX_CORE -D TOOL_FAMILY=llvm -D TOOL=llvm -D _WRS_KERNEL -D _WRS_VX
    _SMP -D _WRS_CONFIG_SMP -O0 -g -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations
```

Does anyone encounter this problem before?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Run `clang -v`, with and without the `-g` and compare the flags it uses for the `-cc1` command. I find that without `-g`, it adds two flags: `-debug-info-kind=limited` and `-dwarf-version=4`. In other words, `-g` is a command for the compiler driver, not for the C compiler itself.